# How can I create a watchman trigger to restart the puma/hanami server

Tags: ruby, watchman, hanami

I have created this watchman trigger:

```
watchman -j <<-EOT
  ["trigger", "/home/gergra/code/essence/essence_backend", {
   "name": "restart_hanami",
   "expression": ["anyof", ["match", "*.rb"]],
   "command": [
       "alert 'restarte hanami'",
       "killall bundle",
       "bundle  exec hanami server"],
   "stdout": ">/home/gergra/hs.log"
}]
EOT
```

It should stop puma with the kill command and then restart it again. If I take a look into the log file, I see that it does do things but the commands are never executed. What am I missing?

Comment: Hanami sadly doesn't seem very active here on stackoverflow yet, you might get better response, or any response for that matter, on the official chat. https://gitter.im/hanami/chat

Comment: I have managed to do the job with entr. This command works for me: ```ag --ruby -l | entr -r bundle exec hanami server``` 
And shotgun is deactivated of course